# Grails Spring Security Plugin Authentication Fails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to configure the spring-security 2.0-RC2 plugin to work with my Grails application. I am able to get it to insert my default admin user with a hashed password into  mongodb. I have also configured spring security to use `emailAddress` instead of `username` as the username field for authentication.

When I attempt to login (with the correct credentials) I am getting an authentication failed error. I'm a bit stumped as to what I am doing wrong. I probably am missing something small that causes this not to work. My configuration is included below.

In `Config.groovy` I have the standard configuration and specify `usernamePropertyName` to point to the email address field instead of username.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'model.Person'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName='email'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'model.PersonRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'model.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap

//Configure URL Restrictions
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
  '/login/**':         [
    'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'
  ],
  '/static/**':        [
    'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'
  ],
  '/**':               [
    'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED']
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'SHA-256'
```

I then have a `Person.groovy` file that was generated by spring security then modified to change username to email address. The generated `PersonRole.groovy` and `Role.groovy` haven't been modified.

```
package model

class Person {
  transient springSecurityService

  String id
  String firstName
  String lastName
  String emailAddress
  String password

  boolean enabled = true
  boolean accountExpired
  boolean accountLocked
  boolean passwordExpired

  static transients = ['springSecurityService']

  static constraints = {
    emailAddress blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false
  }

  static mapping = { password column: '`password`' }

  Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    PersonRole.findAllByPerson(this).collect { it.role } as Set
  }

  def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
  }

  def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
      encodePassword()
    }
  }

  protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
  }
}
```

In my `BootStrap.groovy` I create a default admin user unless one already exists:

```
def adminUser = Person.findByEmailAddress('admin@test.com') ?: new Person(
    firstName: 'Admin',
    lastName: 'User',
    emailAddress: 'admin@test.com',
    password: springSecurityService.encodePassword('admin'),
    enabled: true).save(failOnError: true)
```

I also created a custom `auth.gsp` file as follows, but I have also tried using the default one with the same result.

```
<form action="${postUrl}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
   <h4>Sign in</h4>
   <g:if test="${flash.message}">
      <div class="alert alert-danger" style="padding: 10px">${flash.message}</div>
   </g:if>
   <p>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="j_username" autofocus />
   </p>
   <p>
     <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="j_password" />
   </p>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="${message(code: 'springSecurity.login.button')}" />
 </form>
```

So, does anyone see anything I am missing that would stop authentication from working?

Comment: The property is `emailAddress` not `email` like you have in your config

Comment: Ah good catch, I refactored and forgot to change the setting there. My problem was a combination of this and the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're double-encoding the password. It's done in the `Person` class in `beforeInsert`, and you do it again in the `BootStrap` code. Change

```
password: springSecurityService.encodePassword('admin'),
```

to

```
password: 'admin',
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I had to be doing something silly that I was overlooking. I didn't pay close enough attention to what the generated code did in relation to the code I found as an example for the BootStrap class.

Comment: Also, as was pointed out in another comment I wasn't properly setting the `usernamePropertyName` property.